# Mobile Safari (iphone) Doesn't zoom in when turned horozontally

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, safari, viewport

So I've built a site specifically for iphones that is 320px wide.  It looks great in portrait orientation, but there is a ton of white space on the right when it is turned into landscape mode on the iphone.

I'd like to figure out how to make the viewport zoom into view just the 320px in landscape orientation.  This way, there isn't a ton of white space.

I suspect it has something to do with viewport.  This is what I currently have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
```

But that's not working.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: OK, so i figured out the problem for people who may need this answered.

I was using the MobileBoilerplate framework, which includes this script

http://www.blog.highub.com/mobile-2/a-fix-for-iphone-viewport-scale-bug/

Once I removed that script, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "user-scalable=no", or define "maximum-scale"

It is preferable to define width (of div's etc') in percentage instead of defined pixels. That way the width adjusts to the size of the screen automatically.

There are many good tutorials on responsive design.